# Laravel sendmail: 221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye

Tags: laravel, sendmail

I would like to send emails through a contact form in my Laravel 8 application. In my local instance everything works fine. When I upload it to the web server I receive the following error: 221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye.

[See screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFh9L.png)

**My configuration**
.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@example.de
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example website contact form"
MAIL_RECIPIENT=my@email.de
```

**Mail function in the contact controller**

```
$toName = $request->name;
$toEmail = $request->email;
$toPhone = $request->phone;
$subject = $request->subject;
$message = $request->message;

if ($request->filled('phone')) {
    $message = "Absender: $toName \nEmail: $toEmail \nTelefon: $toPhone" . "\n\n" . $message;
} else {
    $message = "Absender: $toName \nEmail: $toEmail" . "\n\n" . $message;
}

// Send mail
Mail::raw($message, function ($message) use ($toName, $toEmail, $subject) {
$message->to(env('MAIL_RECIPIENT'))
        ->subject('Anfrage über das Kontaktformular')
        ->from($toEmail, $toName);
});
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/886466/smtp-error-554-5-7-1-and-221-2-7-0 related?  The real error would be more useful, but the snarky response rather hides it....

Comment: shot in the dark: does it occur if you use the FQDN in place of 'localhost'? But you really need to get a proper backtrace from the server.

Comment: Super strange. I changed the webhoster and everything works fine... I'm in contact with the old webhoster. If there are any news, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The message `I can break rules, too. Goodbye.` is emitted by the Postfix mail server when it received HTTP verbs (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) on an SMTP listener.  If you're seeing this, it means you have an HTTP client attempting to talk to an SMTP server.

https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_forbidden_commands